# Error while pushing gem to rubygems (Psych::SyntaxError)

Tags: rubygems

I tried doing `rake release` but that hangs..

then seeing this http://help.rubygems.org/discussions/problems/7607-rake-release-hangs-on-new-gem-submission

I've deleted the .gem that got created and built it with

```
gem build mygem.gemspec
```

and then I tried to gem push the gem created and got

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse': (<unknown>): control characters are not allowed at line 1 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse_stream'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:151:in `parse'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:127:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/config_file.rb:318:in `load_file'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/config_file.rb:270:in `load_api_keys'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/config_file.rb:286:in `rubygems_api_key'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/gemcutter_utilities.rb:31:in `sign_in'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/commands/push_command.rb:39:in `execute'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/command.rb:305:in `invoke_with_build_args'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/command_manager.rb:170:in `process_args'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/command_manager.rb:130:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:60:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
```

using ruby 1.9.3 and latest rubygems 2.0.7

What can I do to push my gem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eh

deleted the credential files rubygems told me to created and pushed again, this time logging in myself..

then it worked